# How can a vector be declared in C++ with no errors?

Tags: c++, vector, codeblocks, clion

I'm trying to learn C++, but I've been stuck for a long time because I don't know how to solve the following issue. I have changed from CodeBlocks to CLion hoping for escaping from this issue, but it was not helpful.

I have this code:

```
int main()
{
   vector<int> vect(10);
}
```

And the errors are the following:

```
error: 'vector' was not declared in this scope
     vector<int> vect(10);
     ^
 error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     vector<int> vect(10);
            ^
```

Any idea of how I could solve this?

Comment: Did you `#include <vector>`?  Also, vector lives in the `std::` namespace so you need that as well. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: don't skip the Hello-World example. It should be your first program to compile and run (and it could have clarified 2/3 of your question)

Comment: Had you searched for [`c++ vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vector) here on SO, you would have seen _many_ examples.

Comment: Even if you are an experienced C++ developer, you will always want to check the reference documentation for any library. For the standard library you can use cppreference.com. In the case of the vector you can also see an example of how to use it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector#Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the include the corresponding header

```
#include <vector>
```

Also that class is within a namespace (`std::` in this case), so you need to add that as well

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vect(10);
}
```